# Temporary ASP.NET File conflicts building project in Visual Studio (devex components)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, build, devexpress, temporary-files

I am trying to build my project in Visual Studio (which had been fine until this morning when I came to my machine and it had restarted following a windows update) and now I am getting some errors pertaining to devex components, saying that:

The type 'ASP.components_legendcontrol_ascx' exists in both 'c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\temp\b2334824\769a6106\App_Web_legendcontrol.ascx.7e693e39.3dzqvxte.dll' and 'c:\Users\~\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\temp\b2334824\769a6106

I am running DevExpress DXperience 12.1. I have tried cleaning the directory, getting a latest from GIT, doing a hard reset, removing all files from the temp directories and so on.

I know other developers who are using the same branch of this project from GIT are not experiencing the same problem, so it would suggest it's environment related. Any ideas please? :-)

Comment: You have tried totally clearing the Temporary ASP.NET folder yes?

Comment: Yes, I have tried cleaning the directory and my obj and bin directories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it change anything if you add batch="false" to the compilation element of you web.config, and clean up the temp directories ?

```
<compilation batch="false" defaultLanguage="..." debug="..."  targetFramework="...">
```

Comment: If I apply batch="false" then yes the error will go away as it's simply not compiling the page with the errors in it when you do a build anymore (it will wait until you make a request to the page once the app is up and running). It won't, therefore, actually solve the problem but merely hides it.

Comment: I remember having the same problem on a production server two or three years ago, randomly on ascx files after code delivery. A that time, cleaning up the temp files and do a dummy edit-and-save on the corresponding ascx file would solve the problem. Problems stopped when I started using batch="false".