# Why does aspnet_compiler find multiple types?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5, aspnet-compiler

I'm trying to get our website compiled with aspnet_compiler.  Unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

```
 F:\WebSite\Controls\Control.ascx(34): error CS0433: 
   The type 'Website.Container' exists in both 
   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\079ad281\d925b629\App_Web_maop0n3g.dll' 
   and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\079ad281\d925b629\assembly\dl3\a28aec4c\12bcd7b9_4a0ace01\Website.DLL'
```

Apparently, aspnet_compiler thinks the `Website.Container` type exists in multiple assemblies.  `Website.dll` is one of our website's pre-compiled assemblies.  I believe `App_Web_maop0n3g.dll` is an assembly created by aspnet_compiler.

I've searched through our code base and can't find any duplicate `Website.Container` controls.  It appears that aspnet_compiler is creating a new assembly with this control instead of using the pre-compiled definition.  Clearing the temporary ASP.NET cache doesn't fix the problem.

**How do I debug this problem?**

Comment: does pressing ctrl+f5 resolves it ?

Comment: It tells you _exactly_ where the duplicates are. These are in the `Temporary ASP.NET Files`, which is where .NET places the compiled types from the pages and controls. Looks like an old version wasn't cleared out when it should have been.

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, because I'm compiling the site from the command line.

Comment: You were able to delete all the items in the Temporary folder?

Comment: @Oded I've tried clearing the temporary ASP.NET files, but the error still comes back.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Yup.  Totally empty.

Comment: Do you have IIS configured with the _same_ codebase with several different sites?

Comment: Those paths are kind of strange. Do you possibly have one version from Visual Studio and one from IIS?

Comment: Can you try to close out VS and kill all of its debug IIS things? Then delete the temporary items and try again.

Comment: Maybe this can be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/a/12476097/1236044

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Closed VS, cleared temp files, reset IIS, and still get the error.

Comment: @jbl Nope.  I turned off batch compilation in the web.config *and* via aspnet_compiler's `-fixednames` parameter.

Comment: Time to start going through the paths and application pools in IIS.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Yeah.  I've just launched Process Monitor...

Comment: I'm in the same boat getting Chrome to work.

Comment: Any possibility that the control could be used both in codefile and codebehind controls/pages ?

Comment: @jbl That's it.  The file was using both `CodeFile` and `Inherits` in its `@Control` directive.  Removing the `Inherits` attribute fixed the problem.  If you'll post an answer, I'll accept/upvote it.